# Find object in JSON by knowing his id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, lodash

I have an array of objects, where each object have subobjects with name `linkedParts` (please see example below), how can I find just that subobject based on subobject ID?

I already used something similar to find object by object ID and code looks like:

```
var updatedPart = axCalculation.selectedParts.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.id === response.data.id;
})[0];
```

However I am not sure if I can search just knowing subobjects. If yes how?
axCalculation.selectedParts looksLike:

```
[{
    "id": "1fccb481-53a0-400e-8831-80acd1793bee",
    "euroCode": "7812BGSHABW",
    "position": "REAR",
    "category": "REAR_WINDOW",
    "glassPartType": "GLASS",
    "description": "TODO: DECODE 7812BGSHABW",
    "calculatedPrice": 15768.00,
    "operation": "REPLACE",
    "selectionSource": "MANUAL",
    "linkedParts": []
}, {
    "id": "71e1dc3b-47a2-4406-970a-ef0911c93396",
    "euroCode": "7812AGSHMVZ",
    "position": "FRONT",
    "category": "FRONT_WINDOW",
    "glassPartType": "GLASS",
    "description": "TODO: DECODE 7812AGSHMVZ",
    "descriptionByUser": "TEST DESCC",
    "calculatedPrice": 5749.50,
    "priceByUser": 574.22,
    "operation": "REPLACE",
    "selectionSource": "MANUAL",
    "linkedParts": [{
        "id": "0f45cd6b-7053-4625-8ec9-87281c126e1d",
        "partNumber": "LSD",
        "description": "LEPÍCÍ SADA",
        "calculatedPrice": 562.50,
        "selectionSource": "AUTOMATIC",
        "enabled": true
    }, {
        "id": "61bbbdad-1838-4327-8c38-8808a35a403c",
        "partNumber": "string",
        "description": "GEL POD SENZOR",
        "calculatedPrice": 87.48,
        "selectionSource": "AUTOMATIC",
        "enabled": true
    }]
}]
```

Comment: _I am not sure if I can search just knowing subobjects_ What you need to search? if in `linkedParts` then what?

Comment: Am I missing something or you just need to get the `linkedParts` property of your filter result? `updatedPart.linkedParts`?

Comment: @DavidBarker I already try return obj.linkedParts.id === response.data.id; but this return me nothing. :(

Comment: @Satpal I need to edit that object, so basicly replace some values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer I saw which return effectively the linkedPart object is the reduce/filter one, but when I change the desired id for an invalid one, I still get something. So here the version I would use.

**EDIT : I added a proof that changing the found object is changing the initial one**

```js
var selectedParts = [{
    "id": "1fccb481-53a0-400e-8831-80acd1793bee",
    "euroCode": "7812BGSHABW",
    "position": "REAR",
    "category": "REAR_WINDOW",
    "glassPartType": "GLASS",
    "description": "TODO: DECODE 7812BGSHABW",
    "calculatedPrice": 15768.00,
    "operation": "REPLACE",
    "selectionSource": "MANUAL",
    "linkedParts": []
}, {
    "id": "71e1dc3b-47a2-4406-970a-ef0911c93396",
    "euroCode": "7812AGSHMVZ",
    "position": "FRONT",
    "category": "FRONT_WINDOW",
    "glassPartType": "GLASS",
    "description": "TODO: DECODE 7812AGSHMVZ",
    "descriptionByUser": "TEST DESCC",
    "calculatedPrice": 5749.50,
    "priceByUser": 574.22,
    "operation": "REPLACE",
    "selectionSource": "MANUAL",
    "linkedParts": [{
        "id": "0f45cd6b-7053-4625-8ec9-87281c126e1d",
        "partNumber": "LSD",
        "description": "LEPÍCÍ SADA",
        "calculatedPrice": 562.50,
        "selectionSource": "AUTOMATIC",
        "enabled": true
    }, {
        "id": "61bbbdad-1838-4327-8c38-8808a35a403c",
        "partNumber": "string",
        "description": "GEL POD SENZOR",
        "calculatedPrice": 87.48,
        "selectionSource": "AUTOMATIC",
        "enabled": true
    }]
}];


//Search for the desired object(s)
var wantedId = "0f45cd6b-7053-4625-8ec9-87281c126e1d";
var linkedParts = [];
selectedParts.forEach(function(obj) {
  var foundLinkedParts = obj.linkedParts.filter(function(subObj) {
    return subObj.id == wantedId;
  });
  linkedParts = linkedParts.concat(foundLinkedParts);
});

console.log(linkedParts);

//Modify something in found object
linkedParts[0].partNumber = "My part number";
console.log(linkedParts[0].partNumber);

//Verify in object where initially stored
console.log(selectedParts[1]["linkedParts"][0].partNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have simple search combining `filter` and `some`. This does however make the assumption you want to search a sub-array of objects.

```
let find = (prop, by, where) => {
  return data.filter(d =>
    d[prop].some(sub => sub[by] === where)
  );
}
```

usage

```
console.log(find('linkedParts', 'id', '0f45cd6b-7053-4625-8ec9-87281c126e1d'));
```

Obviously ive made it overly configurable where you pass every property in but if you do not need this you can hard code things.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1pucnaL/) EDIT: Forgot to mention the fiddle uses ES6 syntax which i believe IE doesn't currently support.

[some docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

[filter docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the objects that contains a "linkedPart" of a defined id :

```
var linkedPartId = "0f45cd6b-7053-4625-8ec9-87281c126e1d";

var objBasedOnLinkedPart = axCalculation.selectedParts.filter(function( obj ) {
    for (linkedPart in obj.linkedParts) {
        if (linkedPart.id === linkedPartId) {
            return true;
        }
    }
})[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to flatten the array, and then use filter to find the matching result:

```
function find(ary, subId) {
  return ary.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    return prev.concat(cur.linkedParts);
  }, []).filter(function(item) { 
    return item.id == subId 
  })[0];
}
```

`Array.reduce` will take all the linkedParts arrays and put them into one array.
`Array.filter` will return all matches that would match the passed value.

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zd2mnxah/)

The above was an es5 implementation, it's a lot prettier in es6:

```
function find(ary, subId) {
  return ary.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(c.linkedParts), []).filter(i => i.id == subId)[0];
}
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel this works correctly however I feel like it create new object and no tjust filter in existing one. Am I right?

Comment: @Andurit I doubt this would win a prize for efficiency.  In Es6, with projections it'll look darn purty though.  Filter is going to create a new array object no matter what, but that concat method is going to create one with each iteration.  Honestly unless your application is really speed dependent you probably won't notice.